# angularjs if/else statement and window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am new to AngularJS and recently introduced it into my application. I am trying to re-write some of my existing jQuery code in my controllers, however, on one occasion, i am using:

**jQuery:**

```
if ($(window).width() < 700) {

   $('.productsHeading').on('click', function() {

       $(".productsBody").hide();
       $(".aboutUsBody").show();

   });
}
```

I can get around the `.hide()` and `.show()` using `ng-hide="productsBody"` and `ng-hide="aboutUsBody"` within my DIVs.. These are handled through a `ng-click="productsheading()"`.. However, the issue i am facing is, how do i handle the:

```
if ($(window).width() < 700) {
```

In AngularJS? I am using AngularJS v1.1.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In AngularJS if you want to do changes in HTML or DOM manipulation then recommended or best practices is to use the directive for the same.

Write a directive may be below links are helpful:

[AngularJS event on window innerWidth size change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626357/angularjs-event-on-window-innerwidth-size-change)

http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/SfJ8c/

HTML for the Directive

```html
<div ng-app="miniapp" ng-controller="AppController" ng-style="style()" resize>window.height: {{windowHeight}}
    <br />window.width: {{windowWidth}}
    <br />
</div>
```

Javascript Code for the Directive

```
    app.directive('resize', function ($window) {
    return function (scope, element) {
        var w = angular.element($window);
        scope.getWindowDimensions = function () {
            return {
                'h': w.height(),
                'w': w.width()
            };
        };
        scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
            scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;

            scope.style = function () {
                return {
                    'height': (newValue.h - 100) + 'px',
                        'width': (newValue.w - 100) + 'px'
                };
            };

        }, true);

        w.bind('resize', function () {
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining the code here? What's the `scope.style` and `- 100` for, where are you reusing `'h' : w.height()`

Comment: Scope.style is function called from HTML. Referrer this URL for details http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/SfJ8c/

Answer (score 2):

Most implementations that you will find for retrieving element sizes will have different behavior depending on the browser.

Your best choice is to use jQuery's **width** method which will have same result on any browser.

Btw, there is no need to completely remove jQuery if you are changing to Angular.

For some features jQuery will probably offer the best implementation.