# Angular: Show / hide div:s depending on browser width?

Tags: html, angularjs

Is there a way in AngularJS to show / hide a div depending on the browser with?

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
if (width < 750px)
    ng-hide
```

I hope you got my intention. :-)

Due to accessibility issues, I don't wan't to use this jquery code:

```
@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 600px) {
        myelement {
          display: none;
        }
}
```

This does just hide the html-element, I wan't to remove it from the DOM.

I am thankful for any help I can get on this issue.

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/23078185/1757321

Comment: That might be what I was looking for. Thanks!