# Sidebar left and right fixed with a log of content

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar

I have been on this problem for a long time, i have search quite a lot to find a solution but i'm not a designer so if you find a answer to my problem through others questions just copy the link thank !

I'm working on a web site using angularjs and bootstrap (ui bootstrap too).
Here is a balsamic mock up of what i want the page to look like :

[image: Mock up]

I want the both side bar on the left and the right to be static a little bit like Facebook friends bar. I have found the class"sidebar-nav-fixed" which seemed to work well as long as i didn't put all the content on it. Now i get a sidebar static with no possibility for the user to see the third part of the sidebar left because the element on before are taking too much space. I have try many solutions as :
[angular-event-window-inerwidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626357/angularjs-event-on-window-innerwidth-size-change)

but it never work. The thing is i can't suppress some element from the side bar it need to be there and it will not be convenient for the user if i don't use the sidebar fixed feature.

Thank for you help.

Comment: Are you saying the content on the right side-bar is causing the left side-bar to no longer render?

Comment: @Dreamwalker : no no, for now the right side is not develop. 
What happen is that because the form is too heavy in the side bar the content after is not display on the screen, to see it i have to reduce to 80% the display of my screen.

Comment: Can you link to it or post the code?  When you say "too heavy", do you mean too much content in the left sidebar that it is pushing the right sidebar off the display screen and adding a scrollbar to the browser?

Comment: I can't publish the code. 
The side bar left just go out the screen form the bottom, it didn't affect the side bar right because i put it into a col-xs