# Run function on Desktop only angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement

I've got a function that resizes a viewer on resize. I am trying to disable this on mobile except I'm hitting a wall when In my If Statement. 
Below is my code.

```
  function desktopResizeOnly() {
                if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                    alert('Mobile');
                } else {
                    $scope.$on('window:resize', function(event, bp) {
                        viewer.destroy();
                        update(bp);
                    });
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is `window:resize` an event you're raising somewhere else in the application? Otherwise you're going to want to change the way you're listening for window resizes. [Here's a good start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626357/angularjs-event-on-window-innerwidth-size-change)

Comment: I'll read into this, thank you.

Comment: Explain "hitting a wall when In my If Statement".